# Pandas group by year, date producing spurious values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of daily stats from 1st-Jan-2015 to 3rd-Mar-2019. Reading this to a df and applying groupby month/year produces spurious values right until Dec-2019. Here is the code to get the MultiIndex levels:

```
col_types = {'count': np.int64, 'value': np.float64}
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", sep = '\t', index_col = 1, dtype = col_types, parse_dates=True)

df.dtypes # count int64, value float64
type(df.index) #pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

group_by_list = [df.index.year, df.index.month]
grouped_df = df.groupby(group_by_list).sum()

index_rename_names_list = ['year', 'month']
index_rename_position_list = [0, 1]
grouped_df.index.rename(index_rename_names_list, index_rename_position_list, inplace = True)

grouped_df.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
           codes=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
           3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
           8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 
           4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
           11]],
           names=['year', 'month'])
```

It seems MultiIndex levels are being created even for dates outside the range of the data. Instead of filtering is there a way of avoiding this during the groupby() call itself? Thanks

Comment: What is `df.index.min()` and `df.index.max()` ?

Comment: df.index.min() == (2015, 1), df.index.max() == (2019, 12)

Comment: The data runs only until Mar-19, shouldn't df.index.max() == (2019, 3)?

Comment: @perl: the problem is that it's grouping non-existent data

Comment: When you run code from my answer, do you get the same output as I do?

Comment: @perl: MultIndex shows 60 codes, not 51: `len(df.index.codes[0]) == 60`

Comment: Oh, but you said your `df.index.max() == (2019, 12)`. So the problem is with the index in the original DataFrame

Comment: Indeed, `parse_dates=True` was swapping some of the months and days around. Reading the 'date' col as str and then `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')` solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the index of the original DataFrame `df`, e.g. if we set `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 1}, index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2019-03-03'))`, it works without any issue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 1}, index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2019-03-03'))

group_by_list = [df.index.year, df.index.month]
grouped_df = df.groupby(group_by_list).sum()

index_rename_names_list = ['year', 'month']
index_rename_position_list = [0, 1]
grouped_df.index.rename(index_rename_names_list, index_rename_position_list, inplace = True)

grouped_df.index.max()
```

Output:

```
(2019, 3)
```

P.S. By the way, any reason for not using [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) instead of groupby?